# App crashes when I select "done" button on UIPickerView before explicitly selecting a row

Tags: ios, swift, uipickerview

Unless I explicitly select a row, the UIPickerView crashes and I get the error

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'time interval must be greater than 0'

I understand that it crashes because it's not selecting any one of the rows, and the default value for Time Interval is 0.

So how can I get the `PickerView` to select the first row without me having to explicitly select it myself?

Here is the relevant code:

```
var timerDisplayed = 0


func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
            timerDisplayed = Int(timeSelect[row])!

        }

 @objc func timeClock(){

        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound]) { (didAllow, error) in }
        let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
        content.title = "Time is up!"
        content.badge = 1
        content.sound = UNNotificationSound.init(named: UNNotificationSoundName(rawValue: "note1.wav"))

        let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: TimeInterval(timerDisplayed), repeats: false)

        let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "timerDone", content: content, trigger: trigger)
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request, withCompletionHandler: nil)


        self.timerTextField.text = ("  \(String(self.timerDisplayed))")
        dismissKeyboard()
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(self.Action), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        }
    }

    @objc func Action(){
        if timerDisplayed != 0 {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.timerDisplayed -= 1
                self.timerTextField.text = ("  \(String(self.timerDisplayed))")
            }
        }
        else {
            self.timer.invalidate()
            self.timerTextField.text = nil
            self.timerTextField.placeholder = "   Timer"
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you could just play with your `timeClock()` method, to have this in the first line:

`let timerDisplayed = self.timerDisplayed > 0 ? timerDisplayed : Int(timeSelect[0])!`

So it could look like this:

```
@objc func timeClock(){
    let timerDisplayed = self.timerDisplayed > 0 ? timerDisplayed : Int(timeSelect[0])!
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound]) { (didAllow, error) in }
    let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    content.title = "Time is up!"
    content.badge = 1
    content.sound = UNNotificationSound.init(named: UNNotificationSoundName(rawValue: "note1.wav"))

    let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: TimeInterval(timerDisplayed), repeats: false)

    let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "timerDone", content: content, trigger: trigger)
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request, withCompletionHandler: nil)

    self.timerTextField.text = ("  \(String(self.timerDisplayed))")
    dismissKeyboard()
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(self.Action), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }
}
```

Or you can just put this in `viewDidLoad` to have the first row auto selected:

```
let defaultFirstRow = pickerView.selectedRow(inComponent: 0);
pickerView(pickerView, didSelectRow: defaultFirstRow, inComponent:0)
```

Comment: I edited the answer to show a working sample to autoselect the first row as default in viewdidload or to just adapt your code to work the way you wanted it to be by playing with timerDisplayed variable. Please take a look :D

Comment: Yep, that did it! Thank you!